# How to set ItemTemplate and Template for contexmenu along with data binding for ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, controltemplate

On click of toggle button I want to show a context menu. As I want to change the visual appearance of context menu, I have created controltemplate and data template as below,

```
   <TabItem>
   <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
   <ContextMenu ItemSource="{Binding Collection}">
   <ContextMenu.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
                 <Grid Margin="10">
                <ListBox Width="150" Height="70"/>
                </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                   </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
   </ContextMenu.Template>
   </ContextMenu>
   </DataTemplate>
   </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
   </TabItem>
```

Post this change I could see only a LisBox being shown clicking upon toggle button. I am not able to visualize the Data template that I had set (Checkbox). Data binding is also not working. Not able to figure out what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to the `ItemsSource` of the `ContextMenu` and define an `ItemTemplate` for the `ListBox`:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <ContextMenu.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" Width="150" Height="70">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.Template>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could see no change even after adding this. Will the context menu's itemsource get a knowledge of "Collection", as it is again inside header template of TabItem? Do we need to pass something from TabItem level such that Itemsource of ContextMenu gets to know what it is binded to?

Comment: `Collection` is supposed to a property of the `DataContext` of the `TabItem`. I thought you had sorted out this since you haven't posted anything related to this in your question.